# Let A and B be subsets. Suppose $A ⊆ B$. Show that $P(A) ⊆ P(B)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

("P" is the power set)

this is my proof is it correct?

Assume $A⊆B$. If $x⊆A$, then $x⊆B$, so $x∈P(A)$ and $x∈P(B)$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "Let $A$ and $B$ be subsets." Subsets of what?

Comment: If $P$ is the partitions, then it isn't true, unless $A=B.$ But it is true if $P(A)$ is the power set (the set of subsets of $A.$)

Comment: just subsets...

Comment: But your last iine implies you are talking about subsets, not partitions.

Comment: A set isn't just a subset. A set is a subset of another set. @Samscrhis "Subset" is a relation between sets, not a fact of a single set alone.

Comment: Mathematics requires very specific usage of words and understanding of words.  Surely you mean for $P(A)$ to equal the *power set* of $A$, that is the set of all subsets of $A$.  Do not confuse this with unrelated concepts such as partitions.  Do not use words in incorrect ways for improper uses.  Just because one thing *sounds* like a synonym in colloquial language does not mean you should use it that way in writing since that other word may have a completely different formal meaning in mathematics.

Comment: sorry sir thats right is the power set.

Comment: As for your attempt, now that we are agreed that $P$ represents powerset here, it is... fine... but it is more proper to begin with "*suppose that $x\in P(A)$*" as the very first thing in your assumptions and go through the steps to reach that this implies that $x\in P(B)$ as a conclusion... this rather than having had $x\in P(A)$ appearing deep within the middle of your chain of logic.

Comment: JMoravitz thank you,I would love that you post an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X \in \mathcal{P}(A)$. Then $X \subseteq A$ by definition. But $A \subseteq B$ by assumption, so $X \subseteq B$ and hence $X \in \mathcal{P}(B)$. Therefore, $\mathcal{P}(A) \subseteq \mathcal{P}(B)$.

The proof follows from the transitivity of the relation "is a subset." $E \subseteq F$ means that $t \in E \implies t \in F$. $F \subseteq G$ means that $t \in F \implies t \in G$. Therefore, $t \in E$ implies $t \in G$.

Comment: The first half of your post is correct by itself.  The second half of the post made me have to stop and reread thinking something was wrong.  That is because you reused the symbols $X,A,B$ to mean different things in the first half than in the second half.  It would have been far less confusing if you had used completely different symbols, say $E,F,G$ for instance for the second half for the names of your sets.

Comment: @JMoravitz This is an excellent point. I will change up my notation in the second half to keep things clear.

Answer (score 0):

What is $P$? I think in general this is not true since, if $P(A) = X \setminus A$ then you actually have the opposite implication than what you have stated above.

EDIT: I don't think the proof is correct since $P(A)$ should then be a set of sets. So $x$ cannot be an element of $P(A)$.

Comment: so what would be a good solution?